# Saving state of `EditText` visibility

Tags: javascript, android, android-edittext, visibility

I have couple of **editTexts** that are set to **VISIBLE** and **INVISIBLE** by a button click. I tried saving the state of visibility or invisibility using a `Boolean` and setting it to **True** when it became **VISIBLE** and setting it to **False** when it was **INVISIBLE**. I don't know why but it didn't save the state. Can someone show me an example or steer me the right way to save the state of the **editText's** visibility. I'm an android newbie, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
public void Visible() { ////this button click will make the editext visible, if it is invisible
      if(e1.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
            e1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      } else if(e2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
            e2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
   }



public void invisible(){ //this button click will make the editext invisible, if it is visible
      if(e2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
      {
         e2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      }
      else if(e1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        e1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Why are you assuming that it's not working? Invisible will hide they view but will keep it's place. Try using View.GONE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using `isShown` method of `View`. Then you code will look like:

```
public void visible() {
    if (!e1.isShown())
        e1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (!e2.isShown())
        e2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void invisible() {
    if (e1.isShown())
        e1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (e2.isShown())
        e2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. So can i save these in onPause and recall it in onResume to save whether they were visible or invisible right?

Comment: I figured out how to save them. Thank you for the help